# browse file in iphone

Tags: iphone

I  want user to select file from iphone and upload to a http server. 
 Please help me how this can be done.

Thanks......

Comment: What do you need help with? Reading a directory? Reading a file? Opening up an HTTP connection? Using an HTTP POST query? Setting up a Web server?

Comment: my problem is how can i make user to select a file present in his/her iphone which can be uploaded.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I'm concerned this isn't posable...

Comment: Is there any way to list of files in iphone??

Comment: You can select and access any file in your app's bundle directory, app's Documents directory, maybe a cache and tmp directory as well. Reading files outside the app's sandbox and other locations that don't have a public API might run an app afoul of Apple's rules.